# Thanks note next to the chapter title

Tags: footnotes, chapters

I'm using macro files for my dissertation. 
I want to add thanks notes in every chapter. 
When I use \chapter[title]{title\footnote{aa}}, it works but it is shown with number "1" next to the title. 
I want to make it to the special mark such as star. 
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: \footnotetext{Text} ?

Comment: Thanks. It deletes the number next to the title, but number '0' is in front of the text in the footnote. How can I change 0 to star??

Comment: Is there anything special about your *macro files*? Can you provided a small example of a working document? Some *macro files* do crazy stuff, so a basic answer might not work for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\def\chapterthanks#1{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\heartsuit$}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}% 
\footnote{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter[title]{title\chapterthanks{aa}}
Bla bla \footnote{bbb}...
\end{document}
```

Of course, feel free to change `\heartsuit` to `\ast` or whatever more serious.

Comment: in words- put `\def\chapterthanks#1{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\ast$}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnote{#1}}` in the preamble, then use \chapterthanks instead of \thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me, always says about an "incorrect chapter definition".

Comment: @sequence The example above still work fine with TeXLive 2020,  so you are doing/omitting something wrongly. By chance, is  the error   "Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition"? That happen if you omit the optional  argument. Without that, the `\chapterthanks` need a `\protect` before, but really it is not a good idea omit `[title]` here (unless you want the footnote also in TOC and the heart symbol in  every odd header   of the chapter).